Issue with Azure Function App QueueTrigger and AzureAppConfiguration Integration
I am currently working with an Azure Function App and several microservices that utilize Azure App Configuration. My goal is to use Azure App Configuration as a single source of configuration across all applications.
The function app includes a QueueTrigger that should be triggered based on key/value pairs managed in Azure App Configuration. However, I am encountering an issue where the function app does not trigger as expected.
During troubleshooting, I discovered that the function app only triggers when I add the key/value pair to the ENVIRONMENTVARIABLE section of the Azure Function App. This results in having to manage duplicate key/value pairs both in the ENVIRONMENTVARIABLE section and Azure App Configuration, which I want to avoid.
Could someone please help me understand why the Azure Function App is not triggering based on the key/value pairs managed in Azure App Configuration? Any insights or solutions to eliminate the need for duplicate key/value management would be greatly appreciated.
[Function(nameof(DemoFunction))]
public async Task Run([QueueTrigger("%" + AppKeys.DemoQueue + "%", Connection = AppKeys.AzureWebJobsStorage)] string message)
{
}

Here AppKeys.DemoQueue is managed both ENVIRONMENTVARIABLE (AzureFunctionApp) and as well as AzureAppConfiguration which should not be case. If I remove it from ENVIRONMENTVARIABLE then in that case the function app is not getting triggered whenever there is any message added to the AzureQueue.

Can anyone help me here with some code sample which will serve as a reference for my implementation?

Azure Functions in isolated process do not support triggers from external configuration sources like Azure App Configuration. Here's a link to track the progress of this feature: Support expression resolution from configuration sources registered by the worker
As a workaround, you could use App Configuration references for App Service and Azure Functions.

Thanks a lot @Avani Gupta for sharing the details. It helped me to understand it further better :).
